# GROUP_CONCAT with two fields

Tags: mysql

My table has two fields (ID and Status)

I'd like to get a `group_concat` of the count of each status for each ID.

```
ID  Status
1   True
1   True
1   False
2   True
2   False
2   False
```

I'd like my results to be

```
ID Group_Concat
1  (True-2, False-1)
2  (True-1, False-2)
```

I can parse the True-# / False-# in PHP...unless there's a way to make that a separate field in the group_concat?

I've played with the following, but to no avail..it keeps making a separate row for each ID and Status. This will be part of a larger SELECT but I don't think it's relevant to clutter this question up with that SQL.

```
SELECT ID,Status, GROUP_CONCAT(c) 
FROM (
  SELECT ID, Status,COUNT(Status) c 
  FROM buyer_advert GROUP BY ID,Status
) a GROUP BY ID, Status
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this by adding a `concat` inside the `group_concat` like this:

```
SELECT 
  ID,
  GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(Status,'-',c),' ' ORDER BY Status DESC) 
FROM (SELECT ID, status, COUNT(Status) c
      FROM buyer_advert 
      GROUP BY ID, status
     ) a 
GROUP BY ID;
```

[Sample SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8ee5d/17)

Answer (score 1):

Use a subquery:

```
select id, group_concat(concat(status, '-', cnt))
from (select id, status, count(*) cnt
  from mytable group by 1, 2) x
group by 1
```

See [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/51d82f/1)